# Cadastro de login em php

Tags: php, javascript

Seguinte pessoal, estou desenvolvendo um trabalho para o curso e estou criando um sistema de cadastro de login, está funcionando quando envio, porém cada vez que entro na pagina novamente pelo localhost ela cria uma linha com dados em branco e como consequencia acaba usando uma linha desnecessaria e ocupando um dos codigos(auto_increment).
Segue abaixo a pagina: (está com bootstrap)

http://pastebin.com/DLkCg2RY

db:
tabela usuarios possui apenas nome e senha como varchar.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Coloque o código aqui também !!! Link aqui não é muito recomendável se o mesmo é um item principal da sua duvida, só mesmo como referencias

Comment: O codigo está cortando no php, é minha primeira vez no fórum, para evitar erros colei o codigo em pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código PHP deve ser alterado

```
    ob_start();
    include ('conect.php');
    if(isset($_POST['nome']) and isset($_POST['senha'])){
        $nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : '';
        $senha = isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : '';
        $sql = "insert into usuarios (nome, senha) values ('$nome', '$senha')";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

No caso do `isset` verificamos primeiro se existem nome e senha a serem incluídos, se for o caso, insere no banco de dados, evitando assim, linhas desnecessárias no banco de dados.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!

Comment: Ok, beleza. Marca minha resposta como certa.. (só clicar num checkbox ao lado da minha resposta) :)